# Ubuntu 16.04 rc.local - not running at boot

Tags: ubuntu, service, system, local, rc

i got an executable which i would like to run at startup.

First of all i checked if my executable works in terminal:

```
/absolute/path/to/executable
```

**-> works**

So i added it to my rc.local:

```
/absolute/path/to/executable
```

**-> didnt work at startup**

As this executable runs infinite, i changed it to:

```
/absolute/path/to/executable &
```

**-> didnt work at startup**

So i thought, maybe it needs some time before i can run it, so:

```
/bin/sleep 30 && /absolute/path/to/executable &
```

**-> didnt work at startup**

Well here i am with my rc.local not working.

What did i do in addition to that?

I tested if i can trigger rc.local directly by:

```
sudo sh /etc/rc.local
```

works, after 30 seconds my service appears with its process id !

So what is wrong in my setup?

Thanks and Greetings!

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [ubuntu.se] or [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. The [help] has more information if you need it.

Comment: might this be informative: https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-rc-local-run-on-startup ?

Answer (score 0):

chmod +x /etc/init.d/rc.local

vi /etc/rc.local

Replace #!/bin/sh -e to #!/bin/bash

sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service

sudo reboot

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried all same suggestions on Ubuntu 16 with no luck (my rc.local executes fine on Ubuntu 18)

Here's my working hack:

Open up startup applications and add a new job.

I used this for the command:

```
bash /etc/rc.local
```

Make sure the script is executable (chmod it)

And that's it... You could do this with any script... it doesn't have to be rc.local... see the screenshot for clarity:

[image]